# Bad origin PSI scores for desktop

Tags: wordpress, performance, google-chrome, core-web-vitals

Could you explain me how its possible to have so bad origin data for desktop?

[image]

After finished optimization web vitals for mobile, day by day, are getting better (+6% good in few days).

I also watch desktop scores and they are not going better at all. FCP and LCP are still growing.|

How is it possible?

I tested all important page / page groups (frontpage, shop, categories, products) and for desktop it has always 100% performance score and very low times.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you serve responsive images? Perhaps the larger desktop images are heavily unoptimized.

Comment: @RickViscomi yes, I use smush pro + webp conversion by separate plugin. All images seems to be served well. No warning from PSI about wrong image sizes.
Fcp time for desktop seems impossible in PSI reports. Every page is 99-100 in gtmetrix and PSI. I know that origin data is from all users but cannot find any situation which may provide so long loading time for FCP and LCP...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CrUX Dashboard](https://datastudio.google.com/s/tCoNOiQyIZY) the problem seems to be the [Time to First Byte](https://web.dev/ttfb/) (TTFB) of desktop experiences:

[image: Desktop TTFB is 6% good and 89% poor as of October 2021]

Desktop TTFB is 6% good and 89% poor as of October 2021. Compare that with mobile experiences:

[image: Mobile TTFB is 52% good and 29% poor as of October 2021]

Mobile TTFB is 52% good and 29% poor.

It's unusual to see such a disparity between desktop and mobile TTFB experiences for the origin, since the server typically doesn't care what device type the user is on. If anything the mobile experiences tend to be worse because they're connected via slower cellular network infrastructure, compared to desktop WiFi, which is traditionally faster.

Consider whether there's anything disadvantageous about the way your desktop users **access** your site: population differences, connection issues, etc. Also consider whether desktop users tend to **behave** in different ways than mobile users. For example, if you offer customers a way to log in and pay their bill, it's possible that they almost always do that on a desktop machine and experience a poorer TTFB caused by slow database lookups that wouldn't otherwise be experienced while logged out.

Check out https://web.dev/ttfb/#how-to-improve-ttfb for more general tips on improving TTFB.

Comment: indeed, in the CRUX report, I omitted the TTFB section and for the desktop it actually looks terrible. I would think it should be the other way around - mobile should be worse than desktop but for some reason it is worse for me ..

It's very hard for me to find something that can be a problem in accessing the website - none of the clients complained about anything + I also tested it on various devices. Customers place orders both on mobile phones and on desktops. All transactions are made without logging in - just every client, regardless of the device, goes through the same procedure